# How to send a join/leave message to a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

recently I have been developing a bot for my server and I can't seem to get my bot send messages in a specific channel when a user joins/leaves. I have been researching a LOT and I can't seem to make it work. I've tried `async def on_member_join(member):` and `async def on_member_remove(member)` but after joining and leaving with my alt, it just doesn't even seem to print anything or give an error. (I have `Server Members Intent` and `Presence Intent` turned on in Bot settings)

Here's part of my code:

```py
client = discord.Client()

# on member join
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('member joined')
    channel = client.get_channel(901761695033212939)
    sendmsg = channel.send
    greets = ['greet1', 'greet2', 'greet3', 'greet4', 'greet5', 'greet6']
    n = len(greets) - 1
    num = random.randint(0, n)
    greet = greets[num]
    await sendmsg(f'{member} ' + greet)

# on member leave
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print('member left')
    channel = client.get_channel(901761742609219595)
    sendmsg = channel.send
    byelist = ['bye1', 'bye2', 'bye3']
    n = len(byelist) - 1
    num = random.randint(0, n)
    bye = byelist[num]
    await sendmsg(f'{member} ' + bye)
```

Comment: You also need to enable your intents in the code itself if you have not done so.

Comment: Implement `intents = discord.Intents.all()` into your code. (Above your `client` definition)
After doing this, just say `client= discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Comment: You need to enable the bots intesnts use intents = discord.Intents.all() or client/bot = discord.Client/Bot(intents = intents)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the intents on, you also need to implement them in your code.

You do this by `intents = discord.Intents.all()` and in the client part you need to add `intent=intents`. That should fix it.

Here is the code fixed:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents
)

# on member join
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('member joined')
    channel = client.get_channel(901761695033212939)
    sendmsg = channel.send
    greets = ['greet1', 'greet2', 'greet3', 'greet4', 'greet5', 'greet6']
    n = len(greets) - 1
    num = random.randint(0, n)
    greet = greets[num]
    await sendmsg(f'{member} ' + greet)

# on member leave
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print('member left')
    channel = client.get_channel(901761742609219595)
    sendmsg = channel.send
    byelist = ['bye1', 'bye2', 'bye3']
    n = len(byelist) - 1
    num = random.randint(0, n)
    bye = byelist[num]
    await sendmsg(f'{member} ' + bye)
```